# Is << noun + "for" + gerund >> a valid noun phrase construction to indicate purpose of the head noun in a normal sentence (i.e. not in a title)?

Tags: prepositions, gerunds, legalese, noun-phrases

The following two sentences are patentese (written in language used in a patent):

> A display apparatus includes **a display device *for displaying*** an image.
>
> The display apparatus may include **an optical film *for limiting*** reflection of external, ambient light.

In 'normal' general English, I would say that writing "to display" and "to limit" sounds more natural, where the "to" is short for "in order to", thus using the << noun + "to (in order to)" + infinitive >> noun phrase construction instead.  Also, acceptable would be << noun + "for the purpose of" + gerund >>, but this is perhaps unnecessarily long-winded.

Doing a search online gives acceptable examples of the noun phrase construction << noun + "for" + gerund >> used in titles, for example:

> **A simple method *for displaying*** the hydropathic character of a protein
>
> **Options *for Limiting*** the Potential to Emit (PTE) of a Stationary Source Under Section 112 and Title V of the Clean Air Act (CAA)

For these titles (that are a noun phrase standalone construction without a verb), the << noun + "for" + gerund >> construction is valid and sounds natural to me, but what about if we change these into a normal sentence including verbs, for example:

> We describe **a simple method *for displaying*** the hydropathic character of a protein.
>
> There are **options *for limiting*** the potential to emit (PTE) of a stationary source under Section 112 and Title V of the Clean Air Act (CAA).

The latter quoted sentence sounds fine, but the former sounds a bit unnatural to me due to the << noun + "for" + gerund >> construction within.

[[My original question, referred to these two quotes of titles with this unintentionally misleading comment: *But these seem to be missing a verb, if what is intended is a normal complete sentence.*]]

So, I'd like to ask:
Are the **first** two sentences quoted above acceptable? Do they sound natural? If not, why not and what are the best alternatives?

Comment: You quote four sentences, not two. Where do you need help? Your own sentence both have an _include_ verb, so you're all set.The others are titles, which are rarely sentences.

Comment: Patentese is a very ideosyncratic style, it often sounds unnatural. But if you're writing a patent, I think you're expected to use this traditional style.

Comment: @YosefBaskin I meant the **first** two I quoted and have amended my question to clearly point that out. The fact they contain a verb is not the issue. My question is whether the noun phrase quoted is valid in the examples which are normal sentences (with a verb, etc), rather than in a title (which itself acts like a standalone noun phrase). Thank you.

Comment: It is generally **not wrong** to substitute 'noun + to + verb' with 'noun + for + gerund' in such cases, even though it might sound rather awkward at times. In fact 'noun + for + gerund' is more appropriate in some cases like *'what's your reason **for asking** this question?'* (*'what's your **reason to ask** this question'* would sound awkward.) One reason *for using* 'for + gerund' in your example sentences would be as a short form of ***for the purpose of*** (displaying / limiting etc), the purpose of the proposed design being a key component of the statement for the *purposes* of patents.

Comment: A fork is a device for eating. A fork is not a device to eat. (Just kidding.) ;-)

Comment: With a purpose gerund, _the purpose of_ can usually be inserted between _for_ and the gerund; with a purpose infinitive, _in order_ can usually be inserted before _to_.

Answer (score 1):

The first two sentence are good *for displaying* your question. However, you use display three times (if we include displaying), which is repetitious. How about "a *special* device for displaying ..."?

There is a difference between *to display* and *for displaying*, and you have the right one to my ear. Use 'to act' in such settings to mean a direct cause and effect, not just an option:

> I work *to get paid*. That is the reason I work.

Use *for acting* to mean you are offering an option that could be used for that purpose:

> I have a rag *for cleaning* my desk. Remind me to do just that—perhaps next year.

Comment: Note that 'I have a rag to clean my desk' is fine, while 'I work for getting paid' is unacceptable.

Answer (score 0):

They're not complete sentences by themselves, and titles seldom are; I definitely don't think I've ever seen a research paper with the title as a full sentence (think of how you'd label a list: "Items for school", "Places to visit", "Required for playing piano", etc.). Even modifying it to use an infinitive doesn't lead to a perfect sentence. It's either missing a subject or a predicate, depending on how you look at it.

It definitely sounds natural to me, since *for* is very commonly used to imply purpose or intent. And IMHO it definitely sounds less clumsy and awkward than "in order to" or "for the purpose of"; just because you can expand a single word into a long phrase doesn't mean it's correct to do so.

Comment: These don't look like titles to me, Why do you think they're not complete sentence? They each have a subject and a predicate.

Comment: Subject = *A display apparatus*, verb = *includes*, object = *a display device for displaying an image*

Comment: My issue is that the **first** two sentences I quoted sound a little unnatural, and have amended my question to clearly point that out.  I have no issue with titles not being a complete normal sentence. I have edited that part of my question, to clarify what I meant.

Comment: OK, but his question is about the first two, your answer is about 3 and 4. Read the last paragraph, which starts with "So, I'd like to ask:".